# Access EditText value in different fragments. SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem with the the EditText on my HomeFragment. I'm trying to input an IP address on 4 EditTexts (firstDigits, secondDigits, thirdDigits and fourthDigits) and display it on my TextView (server). My problem is, it is not saving. **I also want it to show on other fragments.** Anyone? :(

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView loggedName, loggedEmail, server;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    Button bConnect, bClear;
    EditText firstDigits, secondDigits, thirdDigits, fourthDigits;


    public HomeFragment() {

        View v;
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        server = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.server);
        firstDigits = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.firstDigits);
        secondDigits = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.secondDigits);
        thirdDigits = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.thirdDigits);
        fourthDigits = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fourthDigits);
        //loadSavedPreferences();

        bConnect = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bConnect);
        bConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getActivity())) //returns true if internet available
                {

                    final TextView server = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.server);
                    final EditText firstDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.firstDigits);
                    final EditText secondDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.secondDigits);
                    final EditText thirdDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thirdDigits);
                    final EditText fourthDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fourthDigits);
                    server.setText(firstDigits.getText().toString() + "." + secondDigits.getText().toString() + "."
                            + thirdDigits.getText().toString() + "." + fourthDigits.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        bClear = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bClear);
        bClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final TextView server = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.server);
                final EditText firstDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.firstDigits);
                final EditText secondDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.secondDigits);
                final EditText thirdDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thirdDigits);
                final EditText fourthDigits = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fourthDigits);

                server.setText("Device Network Address");
                firstDigits.setText("");
                secondDigits.setText("");
                thirdDigits.setText("");
                fourthDigits.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        return v;


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    }



    public void onClick(View v) {


    }


}
```

Comment: We'd like to see how exactly are you saving and loading the address in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Is not so clear what you are asking, where do you want to store the IP address? why are you on every onClick button declaring  a new textview and editText?